# Docker immediately stops the container

Tags: java, docker

I try to use a Java container which is linked with another container, but the container stops immediately. Is their a way to let it started ?

My java Dockerfile show like this:

```
#
# Oracle Java 8 Dockerfile
#
# https://github.com/dockerfile/java
# https://github.com/dockerfile/java/tree/master/oracle-java8
#

# Pull base image.
FROM debian:latest

# Install Java.
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list && \
  echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list && \
  apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886 && \
  apt-get update && \
  dpkg -P oracle-java8-installer && \
  apt-get install -f 


# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

CMD["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Could you please add the command you execute please. Do you use `-it` option ? Note that the docker image [`java:8`](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/java/) is also avaible.

Comment: Could you paste the run command that you are executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run your container in interactive mode?

```
docker run -it myimage
```

Please note you don't need to create your own java image, you can run container with this command

```
docker run -it java:8 /bin/bash
```

Comment: I know that. I use this in my Dockerfile, and I custumize my commands in the docker-compose.yml.

Finally, I find, ouch ! I use a docker-compose.yml file so I have to add "tty: true" to my java container configuration and it run without stop ;)